# Is a sip address the same as an email address?

Tags: sip

How do sip addresses work? Is every email address a sip address? Like can I just ask two people for their email address and create a sip session between them? Can I issue sip addresses by creating emails for users? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

SIP address (more precisely: SIP URI) looks like an e-mail address but indeed it has totally different meaning. For example:

```
 sip:john@example.com
```

means that there is an account named `john` on SIP Proxy server `example.com` (or on SIP Proxy server resolved from `example.com`).
When user `john` starts own SIP client, it sends a register message to SIP Proxy server. Thanks to this, the SIP Proxy server knows whether `john` is registered as well as his current IP address.
When other SIP user intends to create session with `sip:john@example.com` the following steps are performed:

1. `example.com` is translated into domain name of SIP Proxy server using DNS SRV.
2. The `INVITE` message is send towards this SIP Proxy server.
3. If `john` is registered, the `INVITE` is transferred to his client. If not, `404` response is sent back to originate user.

According your questions:

- Is every email address a sip address?  *Definitely no.*
- Like can I just ask two people for their email address and create a sip session
  between them? *No.*
- Can I issue SIP addresses by creating emails for users? *No.*

Comment: Right answer. SIP allows email addresses to be reused but it is a administrative problem not a technical problem. An institution with a  a DNS domain may provide that service for that domain but there is no such think equivalent to the managed public numbering plan of Telecom providers.